# Is there any loopback 3 function that can help in modifying and then building the filters?

Tags: loopbackjs

I need to apply some filter by default. So far I have reached up to this point:

`Project.find = function (filter, callback) {
    return override.apply(this, arguments);
}`

Now I want to apply my default filter here too along with the filter which has been passed by the user. How to achieve this? Do I need to manually handle this or is there any built-in solution for this provided by loopback 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could use is the 'before remote' hook on find, where you have access to the whole request body, so you could modify that depend on the system state. So for example:

```
Project.beforeRemote('find', function(ctx, next) {
    console.log('whole request: ', ctx.req);
    console.log('request body: ', ctx.req.body);
    console.log('request params: ', ctx.req.params);
    //... add filtering
    next();
});
```

Otherwise, if you would like to apply the filtering to each Project.find(..) call, you need to use an operational hook for 'access', but then you have less information in the context, for example, you don't know who is calling the command.

I strongly recommend reading great loopback documentation regarding [operational](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Operation-hooks.html) and [remote hooks](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-hooks.html).

Comment: Thanks ! hook for 'access' is what I needed